# Scalar and Vector point function

Tags: vector-analysis

I am unable to understand the concept of scalar and vector point function.I only understand that it is definein scalar and vector field respectively but unable to understand its meaning.

Comment: A scalar field f(or function - same thing) is a function of several variables taking numerical values. e.g. the temperature at any point in a room depends on position and has a numerical value. A scalar filed is a function of several variables which takes vector values e.g the velocity of water in a river is a vector quantity and depends on position in the river.

Comment: Clear me with another examples.